# How to use or operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
'''
make a test to test how much you understand the code for the project

what to do


functions:
print() input()

'''
```

I'm new to Python. I'm wondering why this program gives me 'correct!' when I enter any other words but not 'A' or 'a'. I want this program to answer me 'correct only when I type 'A', or 'a'. I think I still fully don't understand what or operator does or something else I should understand. Please help me out with this.

```
print('do you wanna take the test?(yes/no):')
answer = input()
if answer == 'yes':
    print('Q1. What do you need to think of first when to make a program?')
    print('A. What program I make? B. Write code first.')
    print('Choose which one is correct(A/B):')
    while True:
        A1 = input()
        if A1 == 'A'or 'a':
            print('correct!')

        else:
            print('Try again.')
            continue
else:
    print('May your heart be your guiding key.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if A1 == 'A'or 'a'`  will be interpreted as `if (A1 == 'A') or 'a'` and since 'a' is always `True`(a non-zero value), the condition will always be `True`.

On the other hand, if you write the conditional statement as `if A1 in ['A', 'a']`, this will check if either `A1=='A' or A1=='a'`.

Comment: `if A1 == ('A'or 'a')` outputs false if `A1 = 'a'`

Comment: That is because, python interpreter willl first check ('A' or 'a') and will return the first string  'A' which is obviously not none. And therefore, when it compares with A1 it returns false when A1 is 'an

Comment: Thanks for your help. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
A1=='A' or 'a'
```

Check if A1='A' and then if 'a' is not None. Here the second check is obviously true, because the string holds the value 'a'

Therefore the condition that you need to use is

```
if A1 in ('A','a'):
    #statements to be executed if the if condition is satisfied.
```

That is, it will check if A1 holds any value given in the list ('A' ,'a')

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. This helps a lot.

Comment: @TsubasaWingOmi If a solution answers your question, you can upvote or accept it as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)